# Delete multiple row in the table using WITH and Partition in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete multiple duplicate rows/data, but the problem is
MySQL said:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM studentTable WHERE RowNumber > 1' at line 6

Here's my Code:

```
WITH studentTable AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY studentID ORDER BY studentID) AS RowNumber
   FROM student_quiz
)
DELETE FROM studentTable WHERE RowNumber > 1;
```

Here's the result of Select Version:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXbBR.png)

I found this code in the youtube and this video was uploaded 11 year ago, So I'm not sure if this code still working in the current version of MySQL. I hope you can help me with this problem. Thank you!

Comment: mariadb is not mysql so I have added the correct tag. Please also publish the result of select version().

Comment: Please show us some sample data. Are there other columns in the table?

Comment: MariaDB is not compatible with MySQL in all cases. In this instance, MySQL supports `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` after a CTE, but in MariaDB's implementation, it only supports `SELECT` after a CTE. This is an example why it's important that we all consider MySQL and MariaDB to be different databases, not drop-in replacements for each other. They have a common ancestor circa 2010, but they have both changed since then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither MySQL nor MariaDB support updatable CTEs.

*If* your table has a primary key, say `pk`, then I would recommend a simple self-join:

```
delete q
from student_quiz q
inner join (select id, min(pk) pk from student_quiz group by id) q1
    on q1.id = q.id and q1.pk < q.pk
```

Basically, for each `id` this retains the row with the smallest `pk` and delete the others, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Since the CTE is not updatable, you need to refer to the original table to delete rows using `JOIN` :

```
WITH studentTable AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY studentID ORDER BY studentID) AS RowNumber
   FROM student_quiz
)
DELETE FROM student_quiz
USING student_quiz join studentTable on student_quiz.id = studentTable.id
WHERE studentTable.RowNumber > 1;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/EQuRlFLk)

Comment: I try your code but I encountered some error: 

WITH studentTable AS
(
   SELECT  id, studentID, quizID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS RowNumber
   FROM student_quiz
)
DELETE FROM student_quiz
USING student_quiz JOIN studentTable on student_quiz.id = studentTable.id
WHERE studentTable.RowNumber > 1;

Error:
2 errors were found during analysis.
Unexpected keyword. (near "join" at position 183)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "join" at position 183)

Comment: Which version of mysql are you using ?

Comment: @SelVazi they are using MariaDB (from the error message they show, though it doesn't show version).

Comment: @testertested this syntax is only supported in mysql, not mariadb (through at least 11.0.1), though the statement in the question (modifying the CTE itself) is supported by neither